# How can I find the definition of a javascript function on a third party website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, definition

How can I find the definition of a Javascript function on a third party website?

I am looking for a certain Javascript function's definition, but it's not in the source code of the page I am looking at, and it seems like a lot of work to go through all the Javascript links on the page, and all the Javascript links on those pages, etc, to find the definition of that function.

Comment: Your typical in-browser development tools give you the ability to inspect all javascript loaded into a page.  Now debugging through 3rd-party javascript may not always be fun if it has been optimized for download (i.e. short, meaningless variables names, no whitespace in code, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

YES! Found this out today. I use Google Chrome's Developer Tools (F12) but can be done on **most** browsers.

Find the item you want to find the function by right clicking the button etc and then it will bring you to the code in the "Elements" tab.

..from here you can click on "Event Listeners" tab on the right and from the drop-downs, see all the event listeners attached to this element.

Finally clicking on these will bring you to the exact location of the function.

Comment: You can do that with any browser, like Firefox (very useful is also the addon "Firebug" for Firefox), Opera, Google Chrome or Internet Explorer.